# Priority queue with changing values of key

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures

I  must to simulate a priority queue. Keys in queue are periodically changed. Queue must be able: add element and delete element. What is the best way to do it (with the best complexity)? What is the best data structure?

Comment: add/delete elements: only the min/max? or an arbitrary element? also, modify element, what is the input? the actual object? and thus searching is not needed?

Comment: Is this Homework? please review [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for the recommended way to ask about homework problems.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107068/delete-ith-node-from-a-heap/5107113#5107113

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend one of two approaches:

1. (Advanced) Use a heap data structure as used by Java's PriorityQueue implementation.  When an element's priority changes you will need to perform "sift up" and "sift down" operations on the heap to ensure that the top of the heap still represents the highest element in the priority queue.  Sift-up and sift-down are operations that form part of [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort).
2. (Simple) Use an unordered list as your priority queue.  This means that elements can be inserted with O(1) access time and adjusting an element's priority does not involve any manipulation of the data structure.  However, the trade-off is that accesssing the highest priority element is O(n).

Comment: You mean finding highers element is O(n), not O(1). also note, that if there are O(2^k) total ops, the list solution will have worth performacne, where k is the number of head ops. also note that suggestion (1) assumes you have the actual object you are modifying, and not only its key, because finding the object from a given key is O(n) with java's PriorityQueue

Comment: Yes that's a fair point - I am assuming that the object is able to update its own priority or that the application already has a reference to it; searching for it is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a data-structure that can support constant changes in arbitrary keys, and removals/additions of arbitrary keys [arbitrary == not the head in this answer], a regular heap won't do the trick, since it doesn't guarantee quick search for arbitrary elements, only to the head.

You could go for a fully ordered structure, such as a [balanced BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), and cache the min/max whenever the tree is modified. [the min is the leftest element, the max is the rightest element].

This will allow you:

delete,modify,add: `O(logn)`

findMin/findMax: `O(1)`

Comment: Why not just use an unordered list?  That will allow you to find the min / max in O(n) but insertions will be O(1).

Comment: @Adamski: The OP wants a priority queue, so I assume the head is needed often enough. note that unsorted list will be better only if `numOfAllOps = Omega(2^numHeadOps)`, I assume it is not the case.

Comment: If the change is, then I must change all keys. Is BST applicable, when must be all keys changed thru one operation "change"?

Comment: @user1014881: most of BST implementation doesn't allow a `change` op, but you can create one by simply removing and reinserting the element with the changed key, since both ops are `O(logn)`, the change method will also be `O(logn)`

Comment: So, I simulate a warehouse. Each item in warehouse has the priority. Items go in and out. Item with biggest priority go out first. Operation "change all item priority" can be required in the proces (fill and flush). Any idea?
Thaks Petr

Comment: @user1014881: what does "change all item priority" do? change the priority of all items with a given number? is this number mutual to all elements? or is it distinct for each element?

Comment: The number is distinct for each element. I must walk thru all elements and change key to different value for each element.

Comment: @user1014881: and do you also have an op that change only one element? if not, just use a regular heap...

Comment: This method doesn't work within the time bounds if the priority values are distinct from the values, like scheduling jobs or something like that. You could potentially have lots of jobs with the same priority, so you would end up having to do linear search to find which one's priority needs to be modified. Better to implement a heap yourself and for each of your items keep track of where in the heap each item is (which can be maintained alongside the heap with 1-2 extra lines of code total) and then do sift-up/sift-down as is suggested below if you want to change priorities.

Answer (score 1):

It's always difficult to say what the "best" data structure is. In general, a binary heap makes a very good priority queue, although it is difficult to change an item's priority. What I did in the past is create a data structure that combines a dictionary and a heap. The dictionary is keyed by the item's identifier, and keeps track of each item's location in the heap. When an item is added, removed, or moved in the heap, its location is updated in the dictionary. This turns out to be inexpensive.

Now when you want to change an item's priority or remove an arbitrary item from the priority queue, you can look it up in the dictionary (`O(1)`) to get its position in the heap. From there, it's an `O(log n)` operation to move or remove it.

You could also use a balanced binary tree for your priority queue. It's easy enough to keep a "lowest node" pointer, and operations on the tree are `O(log n)`. If insertions and removals are fairly well scattered out, this should perform reasonably well. The drawback is that the code to implement a self-balancing binary tree is a bit involved.

Another possibility is to use a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) for your priority queue. My tests show that a skip list priority queue compares favorably with a binary heap based priority queue, but has one big advantage: looking up an item is `O(log n)` rather than `O(n)`. And a skip list isn't much more difficult to implement than a binary heap.

I would tend toward using the skip list because it's easier to manage than the combined heap/dictionary, and it will perform better than the balanced binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just storing numbers as keys, the ArrayList class should work fine.

```
queue = new ArrayList<int>;
queue.add(27);
```

Comment: But. If I would change priority I must walk thru "n" elements. If I would choose "m" elements with highest priority I must walk thru "m*n". It isnt optimaly..